# Removing Junction Box with extra wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, junction-box, renovation

I've removed a few junction boxes to install recessed lighting however this one is giving me an issue. I have attic access and used it to get the junction box detached from the studs and ready to move but it won't budge because there's wire flowing through it from one knockout to the next one then back into the conduit in the attic. Is the only answer cutting the box and fishing out the wire?

[image: Here's a Pic]

Comment: Can you better explain why you must remove junction boxes to install recessed lights, and how you dealt with the conduits and wires at the boxes you did remove?  Leading to: what were you expecting by disconnecting this one from the framing *before* having a plan?

Comment: You need to remove (or cut) the wires and reroute/repull them to the new location(s). That's the whole point of using conduit. Cutting the box is not even on the list of reasonable options.

Comment: Given the difficulty of removing this box, you could leave it there and put a low profile surface mounted  LED fixture there.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 or 3 ways to handle this, but first I would point out that you have more than 2 conduits involved here.  I count at least 4 conductors passing through the box via all 4 conduits.

The other concern is that you don't have service loops for these pass-throughs.  That means one less option, no cutting the wires, because the wires are too short.

Cutting the box is not a good option, because it's too easy to damage the wires.

The next first step is to identify those 4 wires.  I would start in the attic and try to figure out, of those 4 conduits, which 2 ends are nearest this box?  If you're lucky it won't be too far and not too many bends.

Remember to hook a string to the far end of the wires so that you'll have a means to pull things back into the conduit later.

You'll need to pull all 4 of those wires so that there's a loose end for each.  I would tag each pair of wires and tag each conduit or string so that you remember where to put things later.

Now is also a good time to consider the box fill calculation, and whether you can splice and pull new wires to prevent this problem in the future.